# Jeditable - Maxlength on inputfield, and flicker on blur

Tags: javascript, jeditable

I'm using Jeditable to be able to edit li's in a todolist. (i use it because contenteditable doesn't work with drag&drop..). I have to questions:

1. Can i set a maxlength on the inputfield? tried to edit the Jedit-file as the first googlehit says but it doesn't work.
2. When I blur an input field after editing it flickers, first the input field disappear and then it pop-up again and disappear very quickly. This is quite ugly.. Anyone knows what it might be wrong?

Comment: oh! http://blogpad-online.blogspot.se/2010/10/jeditable-maxlength_12.html this worked on the NOT-minified version to fix maxlength.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maxlength is not supported by Jeditable 1.7.2.  As @tobbe mentioned, there is a code fix here http://blogpad-online.blogspot.se/2010/10/jeditable-maxlength_12.html

That code fix has been translated into a pull request so if you want to get it straight from github, you can here: https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_jeditable/pull/32

Comment: You have suggested perfectly ;)